# Isn't the formula and definition of fringe width given by my book wrong?

Tags: optics, interference

The definition of fringe width given by my book can be understood from this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Xiq.jpg). According to [Byju's](https://byjus.com/jee-questions/what-is-fringe-width/#:%7E:text=The%20distance%20between%20two%20consecutive,called%20the%20central%20bright%20fringe.), the distance between two consecutive bright or dark fringes is called the fringe width: this opposes the definition of fringe width I got from my book.

As the definition of fringe width is wrong, therefore my book got the formula for fringe width wrong as well: fringe width, $\delta x=\frac{\lambda D}{2a}$[wavelength = lambda, length of separation of the screen from slit = D, length of separation of two slits = a]

The above formula was derived from this formula: distance between two consecutive maxima or minima $\Delta x=\frac{\lambda D}{a}$. According to my book, the width of a bright fringe and a dark fringe is equal (see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4Xiq.jpg)). If the distance between two consecutive maxima or two minima is $\Delta x$ then the width of $\delta x$ or dark fringe or bright fringe or "fringe width" is $\frac{\Delta x}{2}$.

But I think the book is wrong. The width of a bright fringe and a dark fringe is not equal. See [this](https://scontent.fdac23-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/184836514_2079994848842751_1065657390875429385_n.png?_nc_cat=109&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=6RswdHpQ1TQAX92dShJ&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac23-1.fna&oh=120de36a1dd9aaa79a33ea037214886b&oe=60C78518) and [this](https://scontent.fdac23-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/185057514_462248755039974_7917940190271531574_n.png?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=VPu3Ddy3i_AAX855EFR&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac23-1.fna&oh=8c259966cd608cf767cea6677fb556da&oe=60C711EE). Distance between two consecutive minima or maxima is equal, but the width of a dark fringe and a bright fringe is not equal as is clear from the images.

So, according to my research. the formula $\Delta x=\frac{\lambda D}{a}$ is correct and $\Delta x$ is the fringe width, and the formula $\delta x=\frac{\lambda D}{2a}$ is wrong, and $\delta x$ is not the fringe width.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the book definition is wrong, and you are thinking along the correct lines. Fringe width is defined as the distance between consecutive bright fringes or dark fringes. For Young's double slit experiment, this value is given by:
$$\beta=\frac {\lambda D}{d}$$